# DVR capture card with 4 BNC ports

Tags: pci, windows-xp

Hi I have a capture card and only things I can read from it is:
10104 on the board
and
'Techwell TW6802" on the main chip
I can't find a working driver anywhere.

I can accept any sollution (Even a server related one since this is a place for servers), tried win7 but the board is made for win2000/xp, tried ubuntu doesn't work. I'm on Windows XP now.
Please help

Comment: Looking for drivers is off-topic on [SF]. You should contact the supplier or manufacturer of your card.

Comment: Sorry for that but as I've said, I will accept ANY solution, even server related. desperate now...

Comment: `Solution == Contact Supplier || Manufacturer`

Answer (score 1):

This post probably belongs on SuperUser...Hopefully this can point you in the right direction, this card is made by Hawell a Chinese Manufacturer.  Their website is found [here](http://www.cctvhw.com/english/index.php).  Good luck.

Comment: none of the drivers there work :((

Comment: Should contact them will be the only way as this is the manu. otherwise don't by _cheap_ cards

Comment: Actually one of those drivers worked but not with their software, got another software to use the drivers and all ok. thanx